# Using platform channels in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I  am adding Flutter to my existing Android application. It is possible to use the platform channels to access existing things like shared preference values, handling deep link?

I know about platform channel we have to write it in MainActivity of flutter project by extending FlutterActivty that accesses the native code. I want to access my project specific feature like accessing exiting shared preference values and all.

Comment: Yes, have a look here https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: i can't access my project specific features

Comment: Why do you say that? Plus, FlutterActivity is experimental right now. Go for FlutterView or FlutterFragment inside an Android Activity.

Comment: Yes for adding view we use it, but I want to access my existing shared preference  values in flutter